# How to access array at the server end of tcp/ip socket

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I'm new to tcp socket with c++. I am trying to send a int array over the socket. I write my own client and socket(Both run on winOS). To make I can receive the int array type, I set the recvbuffer as int[] type and force it change to char inside the recv() function. This is part of the code of server:

```
int recvbuf[6];
```

and

```
iResult = recv(ClientSocket, (char *)&recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
```

The result is good, I can print out all the six numbers, which means my client works well. HOWEVER, when I switch the server to another one, which was built-in a sdk and running on linux, I can no longer access those numbers.

For the sdk, I have a I/O looks like this:

```
typedef BYTE char
unsigned int getData(BYTE * data, unsigned int len)
{
    if (_dataFlag == 1)
    {
        if (len <= DATA_LENGTH)
        {
            memcpy(data, _receivedData, len);
            _dataFlag = 0;
            return len;
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(data, _receivedData, DATA_LENGTH);
            _dataFlag = 0;
            return DATA_LENGTH;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The way I access the _socketData is:

```
iResult = _tcpSocket.getData(_socketData, MSG_LEN);
int *ptr = (int *)&_socketData;
```

And use ptr[i] (i = 0 ... 5) to access the numbers. But it doesn't work, I don't get what I want. Could you guys please solve my problem, thx.

There is code how I send int array thru Client:

```
while (1) 
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(open_path);
    if (!infile)
        cout << "error" << endl;

    string str;
    double temp;
    int length;
    int array[6];

    cout << "store to vector" << endl;
    vector<double> ve;
    while (infile >> temp)
    {
        ve.push_back(temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ve.size(); i++)
    {
        array[i] = ve[i] * 10000;
    }

    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)array, (int)sizeof(array), 0);

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        cout << "success" << endl;
        Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly is `receiveData` being populated? What *exactly* do you get from `getData()`? What are you *expecting* to get instead? Assuming the bytes are correctly being exchanged, the first thing that comes to mind is endian. Multi-byte integers *should* be transmitted in network byte order (big endian). Windows is a little endian system. Try using `htonl()` on the sending side, and `ntohl()` on the receiving side, to swap the bytes of the individual integers that you send/receive and see if you get the expected results.

Comment: What you are doing is non portable between different hardware architectures and even different configurations of the same compiler in some instances. Are integers even the same size on both machines? Are they stored the same way in memory? Etc..